# Empty .jar File in Ecilipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i just imported a Jackson's annotation library and imported it into my java application project in eclipse. However, after importing, the package doesn't contain any java files.

If I open the .jar file using  a .zip extractor, all the java files are present.

Anyone knows how to rectify this?

Thanks already.

Screenshot : [Empty](http://tinypic.com/r/118o9w5/8)

Comment: I'm adding the build path. [ Click on add external jars. Then browse. That's how I did it. ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `binary` jars (jar which has the class files), and not the `source` jar files. 
If you add the `source` jar files and imported to your `buildpath` eclipse wont show any `java` files.
Instead first add the jar containing the `class` files, and then you can attach the `source` jar to the `binary`.

Comment: Since, it is not showing anything, it means it's a source file. Now, how to convert it into a binary file? Or is there any way to download binary files?

Comment: maven repo has the jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.0.1

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you Sir.
Can you please elaborate the thing about binary and source .jar files?

Comment: `source` jar has only `java` files and `binary` jars has compiled `java` files ie, `class` files.